# Rails how to insert elements to existing hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ajax request that sends data to my controller, but i want to add elements to the hash before saving it to the db.

My existing hash looks like this:

```
{"application_field_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"10"}}}
```

I also have elements `params[:xposition]`, and `params[:yposition]` that i want to add to the hash above so that it looks like this:

```
{"application_field_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"10", "xposition"=>"1", "yposition"=>"0"}}}
```

How do i go about doing this?

**EDIT**

The reason i'm doing this is because i'm trying to keep track of where draggable elements are dropped on a grid.

In my ajax call, i pass in the x and y position which i get from some "data-id" attributes i placed on the grid.

In my controller method, i currently have `@application.update_attributes(params[:application])`, but it doesn't contain the xposition and yposition and that's why i'm trying to inject them to the hash.

Maybe a better solution would be to manually update the x and y positions in the controller after the update_attributes command?

So it would look something like:

```
@application.update_attributes(params[:application])
@application.update_xposition(params[:xposition])
@application.update_yposition(params[:yposition])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do that differently.

Maybe a better idea would be to have hidden fields in your form with xposition and yposition, for instance.

Could you tell us more about what you're trying to do, what are x/yposition (if they are different for every application, and where do they come from).

To answer your question though:

```
app_attrs = {"application_field_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"10"}}}
app_attrs["application_field_attributes"]["0"].merge!({
    "xposition" => params[:xposition],
    "yposition" => params[:yposition]
})
```

But I wouldn't do that if I were you.

Comment: I'm building a drag and drop interface. xposition and ypoisition are where the draggable element was dropped.

Comment: And when you drop an element, you submit a form?

Comment: I have a submit button that is clicked. There are multiple draggable elements that can be dropped. I'm trying to keep track of the xposition and yposition for each of them.

Comment: I had to use this format `.merge!({"xposition"=>params[:xposition], "yposition"=>params[:yposition]})`, but it worked.